# Multithreading in LLVM

Tags: multithreading, llvm, tbb, cilk, cilk-plus

I need to generate LLVM code that will serve a lot of threads/tasks (hundreds of thousands). These threads should be lightweight like Intel TBB's tasks, golang gorutines or other. Of course they can be implemented with external C++ libraries like mentioned Intel TBB (if it is compatible with LLVM).

I was searching for long time for any information about threading in LLVM and I haven't found much. In [the documentation of LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#threading) there are described some API calls but I think it's not what I'm looking for.

So there are few questions:

1. Is it possible to use technologies like Intel's TBB or Cilk together with LLVM?
2. What threading library should I use in this situation?

Comment: maybe this helps [multithreading...](http://groups.google.com/group/polly-dev/browse_thread/thread/7c7648fc323380de/102e258aafabade2?#102e258aafabade2)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there seems to be a few projects out there that uses intel TBB and LLVM, for example Intel's own opencl SDK used TBB and LLVM for its compiler, http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/